# get location updates from LocationListener isn't working anymore Android

Tags: android, google-maps

So, i currently developing a map based app and follow lots of tutorials to update user location based on whether network or gps provider but i prefer network though. like this:

```
locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    mlocListener = new CustomLocationListener();
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mlocListener);
```

and my CustomLocationListener class is like this:

```
public class CustomLocationListener implements LocationListener {

    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Location Updated");
        userCoordinate = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        // Move the camera instantly to kiel with a zoom of 15.
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(userCoordinate, 14));

        // Zoom in, animating the camera.
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(14), 2000, null);
    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        System.out.println("provider disabled");
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "GPS mode disabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        System.out.println("provider enabled");
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "GPS mode enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

}
```

you know this works well when i compile it and run on my device. it's quickly focus the camera on the user coordinate current position.
BUt somehow one day, when i try my device in some other place with wifi it SUDDENLY! doesn't work anymore!

i try to revert my project to initial commit on my git (when the code works to update user position) but still it doesn't work anymore!

i try to make a new simple project using

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mlocListener);
```

BUT still it doesn't work anymore! why? why? why?

i open map app from google on my phone and it's just normal!
i dont think if my phone is broken! i dunno man! Sony XPERIA Miro

please gimme solution for this...
i'm confused!

Answer (score 0):

To test if your phone is broken or not, go to system settings-->Location services and turn off everything except Google's location service. Now lauch Navigator app and see if the app know where you are. You may have to walk around because the first fix is probably the last known location.

Comment: there's no problem. the navigation app works well. i think it's not broken

Comment: Well that means that there is no fix for that particular wifi. Try some other place or your current place now.

Comment: it's still doesn't work. i used to test this at my campus and it actually works until this phenomenon happens couple days ago. i also test my app on other devices but it's still doesn't work

Comment: That probably means something else and not the location code. Does the location in your code update, I mean do you get any value from onLocationChanged

Comment: nope, not at all with network provider. i've just try using gps provider and it works after 5 min outdoor. is this means that i cant count on wifi or mobile networks as my location source?

Comment: GPS is a lot more accurate but use more battery. The network location is obtained by the nearby cell tower or ip address and then look up the location in a store table.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26836/discussion-between-user724861-and-hoan-nguyen)